# Как передать переменную из Python в PHP?

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, subprocess, file-get-contents

Нужно передать в 10.php переменную hash из файла pyphp.py:

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run(
    ['php', './10.php'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, check=True)
res = (result.stdout)
res = str(res)
warn = res

hash = 'g8sfgnvsf0g8'
file_hash = open("hash.txt", "w")
file_hash.write(hash)
file_hash.close()


print(warn)
```

10.php:

```
<?php
$hash = file_get_contents('hash.txt');
echo $hash;
```

При изменении переменной hash, правильный результат выдается только со второго запуска скрипта. В первый раз warn остается тем же.

Было hash = 'g8sfgnvsf0g8', изменил на '1000' и запустил pyphp.py два раза[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал добавлять третий аргумент `file_hash = open("hash.txt", "w", 0)`, но выдается ошибка `ValueError: can't have unbuffered text I/O`.
Как сделать так, чтобы Python сразу записывал значение в файл? Либо как передать переменную другим способом?

Comment: передавайте как аргумент командной строки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой пример можно использовать:

`subprocess.call(["php","-f","test.php","param0:value0", "param1:value1"])`

В самом PHP используйте переменную `$argv` для работы с аргументами строки. Или можно попробовать работать с JSON форматом. На Python пишите:

`subprocess.call(["php","-f","test.php", json.dumps(your_dictionary)])`

А на самом PHP получаете так:

```
if ($argc > 1) {
  $json_str = $argv[1];
  $_GET = json_decode($json_str);
}
```